# OnClick supresses OnTouch below

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

I have an app with several `ImageViews` that are clickable. All these images are inside a `LinearLayout`.

I implemented an `OnTouchListener` and set it to the `LinearLayout`. When I swipe over it, my `OnTouchListener` calls a function.

The thing is if I start swiping over the `ImageViews` that don't have an `OnClickListener` the `OnTouchListener` works, but when I start swiping over an image that has an `OnClickListener`, then  the `OnTouch` function doesn't work (nor does the `OnClick` of that `ImageView` as it is normal).

I want to know if there is a way to have my `ImageViews` that have `onClick` pass the action to the view below if the user swipes instead of clicks and not pass it if the user just clicks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1738726, instead of adding your solution to the question, you should add it as an answer instead. It would make this better since it will match the Q/A format of the site :)

Answer (score 3):

I manage to do it, the only way i found was using SimpleOnGestureListener.  I copy paste the code if anyone is having the same problem.

Create a class like this:

```
public abstract class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
private Activity activity;

public MyGestureDetector(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
}

public abstract void onRightToLeftSwipe();

public abstract void onLeftToRightSwipe();

public abstract void onTopToBottomSwipe();

public abstract void onBottomToTopSwipe();

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velX,
        float velY) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = (int) (SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f);
    int REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = (int) (SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
            * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f);
    float deltaX = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
    float deltaY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
    try {
        // swipe horizontal?
        if ((Math.abs(deltaX) > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)
                && (Math.abs(velX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                && (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY))) {
            // left or right
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaX > 0) {
                this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                return true;
            }
        } else if ((Math.abs(deltaY) > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)
                && (Math.abs(velY) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) { // swipe
            // vertical
            // top or down
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaY > 0) {
                this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false; // We don't consume the event
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing
    }
    return false;
}

public View.OnTouchListener getGestureListener() {
    return gestureListener;
}

public void setGestureListener(View.OnTouchListener gestureListener) {
    this.gestureListener = gestureListener;
}
}
```

then you have to do this in your Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Initializate your variables here
     // Using Gestures
     MyGestureDetector gestos = new MyGestureDetector(this) {

        @Override
        public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
            // Do whatever

        }

        @Override
        public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
            // Do whatever
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
            // Do whatever
        }

        @Override
        public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
            // Do whatever

        }
    };
```

Last, but not least, you have to put the TouchListener to the layout you want to swipe within and EVERY VIEW IN THAT LAYOUT THAT IS CLICKABLE

```
layoutSwipe = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSwipe);
layoutSwipe.setOnTouchListener(gestos.getGestureListener());
viewInsidells.setOnTouchListener(gestos.getGestureListener());
view2Insidells.setOnTouchListener(gestos.getGestureListener());
```

With this, you can make cliclable your views inside of your layout, if you click it will ONLY perform the click action of the view you clicked, if you swipe it will ONLY perform the swipe action according to your movement.

I spent 4 hours trying to solve this, hope i can save some time to the next one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Kindly update us if you got another way to do it. Thank you again.